# An internal error has occurred. [ CONFIGURATION_NOT_FOUND ] anonimous sign in flutter in firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, authentication

> [firebase_auth/unknown] com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ CONFIGURATION_NOT_FOUND ]

I'm encountering this error when I try to sign in anonymously in Firebase through my flutter app.

I already enabled anonymous sign-in on Firebase console and YES I press "get started".
I want to specify that I'm already using Firebase on the same project using the real time database and everything works perfectly fine.
YES, I did `Firebase.initializeApp();`.

I looked for a solution everywhere but everybody keep pointing at these two issues that are not my case.
I'd really appreciate some help.

This is my Service class:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

class AuthService {
  static final fireBaseApp = Firebase.app();
  Future signiInAnon() async {
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instanceFor(app: fireBaseApp).signInAnonymously();
      print("Signed in with temporary account.");
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      switch (e.code) {
        case "operation-not-allowed":
          print("Anonymous auth hasn't been enabled for this project.");
          break;
        default:
          print("Unknown error.");
          print(e);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That I call in a eleveted button here:

```
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text("Sign in anonimously"),
          onPressed: () async {
           _authService.signiInAnon();
          },
        ),
```